# Shopify: Does different Version of same Theme with different number of posts loses Posts

Tags: shopify, blogs, posts, staging

I have two different versions of the same theme and two different Shopify stores.
One is live and has some latest blog posts,
other one is used for development purpose i.e some styling and has less number of blog posts.

Will download the theme from the development version and publishing it to the live website remove blog posts?

If it does then what is the best way to apply only front-end changes from one store to other?

Answer (score 1):

Blog Articles (Posts I assume) exist in Shopify as resources you create, the same as any Product, Page or Collection. They do not disappear or otherwise change with Theme Changes.

When your theme is set to render a blog, it renders a number of articles based on some criteria. These days, likely a setting you can touch with the Setup of your theme, requiring no code.

If you update a theme, theoretically, the display of blog articles would not change. You should be safe as houses in other words, to play with your theme, and not see a difference in the blog articles save for what you actually change theme-wise or settings wise with regards to rendering a theme.

If you're really interested in the little bit of code involved, check your theme files for blog.liquid and article.liquid for ways you can tweak your display.

Comment: Problem is not with the layout of blog posts
actually I tried uploading the customized theme after publishing theme all of the latest blog posts disappeared and when published the previous theme all came back.

Comment: I stand by my answer. It is correct. It tells you all you need to know.

Comment: The new theme is probably pointing to a wrong blog handle. There should be a setting somewhere in the theme customizer that lets you select the blog to use.

Comment: what is a blog handle. Sorry I am newbie and not familiar with it so much.

Answer (score 0):

> Will download the theme from the development version and publishing it to the live website remove blog posts?

No, your data is complete decouple from your theme.

> If it does then what is the best way to apply only front-end changes from one store to other?

One way to avoid any data sync issue or syncing configuration between environments is to you your production environment as your dev environment.

You can duplicate your production theme, in your production environment and make changes to it and make sure you keep your theme unpublished. Shopify has a "theme preview" feature that allows users to see an unpublished theme, which can be considered as your development theme.

Most likely your environment is out-sync in some way that is why it looks like you are missing your data.